# Weight painting problem with human head

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I have a problem with weight painting the models head, even when I just use automatic weights it does this.

[image]

Whenever I move the head bone, my models face parts don't move perfectly with it, instead the mouth opens, the teeth, tongue and inner mouth move out of the head and the eyelash mesh and brows move strangely with it as well.

Comment: Looks like maybe that part pf the mesh does not completely link to the top bone? Facial rigs often have a primary bone with subordinate children bones that use copy rotation and copy location modifiers to allow motion more complicated than can be achieved by one bone alone.  This may not be the answer, but if you post a screen shot of your weight painting, we could tell.

Comment: in your case only the head bone should influence the head mesh, so probably some other bones have an influence on it, to remove any influence, select the head mesh in Edit mode, go in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, and in the dropdown menu on the right of the list, choose Remove From All Groups. Now use the Weight Paint brush to assign the head mesh to the head bone.

Answer (score 1):

Not really presented as an answer, but I wanted to add these images to my comment above:

Looks like maybe that part pf the mesh does not completely link to the top bone? Facial rigs often have a primary bone with subordinate children bones that use copy rotation and copy location modifiers to allow motion more complicated than can be achieved by one bone alone. This may not be the answer, but if you post a screen shot of your weight painting, we could tell...

[image]

[image]

These images are not my work and are used for educational and explanatory purposes only.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that I had to make the whole head red in weight paint mode.